# Write a csv file to AWS S3 Fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this code in TypeScript that I used to write a csv file to AWS S3, which it works fine locally, and recently I started getting and error saying:

> s3 upload error unsupported body payload object

**NOTES**:

- I'm not passing the credentials because the code is running in the
  same container with AWS S3 (EC2) that's why I don't need to pass the
  credentials.
- I'm printing all the params I'm reading/passing and I    have them
  read properly.

Here is the code:

```
public async writeFileToS3(datasetFile: any): Promise<boolean> {
        try {
            const readFile = util.promisify(this.fileWriter.readFile);
            const unlinkFile = util.promisify(this.fileWriter.unlink);
            const s3BucketName = this.appConfig.get<string>(
                'infra.fileWriter.bucket'
            );
            const s3Region = this.appConfig.get<string>(
                'infra.fileWriter.region'
            );
            this.s3Bucket.config.region = s3Region;
            console.log(
                `datasetFile ${datasetFile.path} ${datasetFile.originalname}`
            );
            const data = readFile(datasetFile.path);
            const params = {
                Bucket: s3BucketName,
                Key: datasetFile.originalname,
                Body: data,
                ACL: 'public-read'
            };
            console.log(
                `params ${params.Bucket} ${params.Key} ${params.Body} ${params.ACL}`
            );
            return await new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
                this.s3Bucket.upload(params, function(err: any) {
                    unlinkFile(datasetFile.path);
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        throw new OperationError(
                            'Error wirting file to S3',
                            err
                        );
                    } else {
                        resolve(true);
                    }
                });
            });
        } catch (err) {
            throw new OperationError('Error wirting file to S3');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`readFile` returns a Promise (you created it with `util.promisify`), thus `data` is a Promise here:

```
const data = readFile(datasetFile.path);
const params = {
  Bucket: s3BucketName,
  Key: datasetFile.originalname,
  Body: data,
  ACL: 'public-read'
};
```

You should await the Promise:

```
const data = await readFile(datasetFile.path);
```